# Is it possible to reset a For Loop?

Tags: java

I have the following code which attempts to return an ordered array from an unordered one. I am using two methods to accomplish this.    I appear to be unable to reset the For Loop in the method BSort.  is resetting For Loops even possible in java?  Any advice would be much appreciated.

```
private int[] myArray;
private int aux;

public int[] BSort(int[] myArray) {
    this.myArray = myArray;
    for (int a = 0; a < myArray.length - 2; a++) {
        if (myArray[a] < myArray[a + 1]) {
            BSortAux(myArray);
            a = 0;
        }
    }
    return myArray;
}

public int[] BSortAux(int[] myArray) {
    this.myArray = myArray;

    for (int i = 0; i <= myArray.length - 2; i++) {
        if (myArray[i + 1] > myArray[i]) {
            aux = myArray[i];
            myArray[i] = myArray[i + 1];
            myArray[i + 1] = aux;

        }
    }
    return myArray;
}
```

Comment: Just change the value of `a` or `i` to `0` or the desired value inside the `for` loop...

Comment: Check out http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html

Comment: Luiggi, I did reset the value of a=0 from the first method. but it just isn't resetting.

Comment: Looks like the code inside the `if` is not getting executed.

Comment: What is it doing because I am willing to bet you are misdiagnosing your problem? What do you see when you step through the code in your debugger?

Comment: This code is a "bubble sort" using for loops.  I am getting the int[] array ordered,.The first method is supposed to get the int[] array plugged back into the second method for ordering if it determines that array[a]<arr[a+1].  The first method is suppose to check from the first element every time the array gets plugged into the second method for sorting.  which is why i am trying to get the value of "a" back to 0.

Answer (score -1):

Is `a` declared publicly somewhere else? Try using another variable other than `a`. There doesn't seem to be enough information for a proper conclusion.

Comment: This should be a comment (which I realize you don't have the rep for). If you are going to post an answer it needs to propose a solution, not a question